# How to restrict my broadcast receiver to only accept broadcasts from certain applications?

Tags: android

I have a service in my app that the customer application can run by broadcasting a request to my app. They have access to the request key. I want to restrict my broadcast receiver to only be able to accept broadcasts from certain package names, for added security.

My Service (simplified):

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private ResponseReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return null; }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        final String ACTION = "my_action";

        // Register receiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        receiver = new ResponseReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final String REQUEST_KEY = "REQUEST";
            String request = intent.getStringExtra(REQUEST_KEY);

            Log.i("MainActivity", "Request from external application: " + request);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".services.MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

How can I make it so that only applications with the package names com.my.application and com.customer.app can send a broadcast to my app?

Comment: That is not strictly possible. You have no way of blacklisting or whitelisting packages, in terms of manifest settings, that can work with your components. One option would be to define a custom permission, then have those two apps request that permission. In practice, this will not work very well, unless all of the apps are signed by the same signing key, so you could use a `signature`-level permission. If the other apps are signed separately, then if they can request the permission (e.g., a `normal` one), so can any attacker.

Comment: You can try [calling `Binder.getCalingUid()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html#getCallingUid()) from `onReceive()` and see what UID you get back. I suspect that the value will be useless (e.g., a system UID). But if you're lucky, it will be the UID of the broadcasting app, in which case you can use `PackageManager` to find out the package name(s) associated with that UID, and ignore broadcasts from packages not on your whitelist.

Comment: Are these other applications signed by the same certificate? you can define a custom permission with android:protectionLevel  signature

Comment: I'm building my app through the command line. It acts as a system app, with user id of android.uid.system. So I'm not building from android studio. How can I apply a key in my case? And won't I have to reassign this key every time I update my application?